# Java- FileWriter/BufferedWriter - appending to end of a text file?

Tags: java, file-io

I've done this before once, I'm trying to replicate what I did so far and this is what I've got:

```
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.P", true));
        System.out.println("entered");
        if (!(newUserName.isEmpty()) || (newUserPass.isEmpty())){
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write("hellotest123");
            writer.close();
        }
```

It seems to find file.P, which is just a txt file, but it doesn't seem to append anything onto it? It enters the code and passes the IF statement fine, but nothing is appended to the text file? I'm slightly stuck!

Comment: How sure are you that your if statement evaluates to true ? debug it or put some debugging tracing inside it to verify.

Comment: Are you sure that you're entering the if?  As a simple test, I'd move your println() statement into the if block.

Alternatively, you can place another writer.write statement on the outside of the block.  If it in fact already went into the block, this write will fail in the form of a IOException.

Comment: yep I have debugged it and stepped through it, evaluates to true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure it is finding file.P and not just creating a new one elsewhere in the file system? Try an absolute path, just to make certain you and the program are looking at the same file.

Edit:

Based on the comment that the file is on the class path you should be using the following method of resolving it:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("file.P");
```

This will find file.P on the classpath in the same "package" or folder as MyClass.class

Comment: ahh ok you were right, that seemed to work calling it from the absolute file path. But, as the file.P is in the same package is there no way i can get it to just look at that? I'd rather not hard code the file path. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you try calling the writer.flush() ? The code looks like it calls flush on close but would be better to confirm this.

2) Can you also print the full location of the file ? Perhaps it is appending in the tmp directory or the wrong location?

Comment: That's not necessary. `writer.close()` will flush the stream.

Comment: close() should flush the Writer.
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29

Comment: still nothing, no error messages or anything. All the code after the If is run, but doesnt seem to do anything!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your `if` statement have two apostrophes and `&&`? requiring user *and* pass instead of no user or pass?

```
if (!(newUserName.isEmpty()) && !(newUserPass.isEmpty())){
```